# Why can't my computer resolve archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt-get

I am trying to install mdadm on a clean installation of Linux Mint from the live CD.

When I request the package sudo apt-get install mdadm, I get the following reply:

Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: What version of linux mint?

Answer (score 2):

In your title, there's a typo: ubuntu, not "unbuntu". Assuming that is *not* the issue, could it be you're on a network where access is forbidden, or that DNS lookup fails? Test access to that site folder in your browser directly; you should see "Index of/" and Ubuntu. 
If it's a DNS issue, you could temporarily use the IP, 91.189.92.201, in your hosts file... but don't leave it that way indefinitely, as IP may change.